# String Index Out of Range DNA Palindrome

Tags: python, string, range, out

I can't figure out why string is out of range, and how to fix it. 
If I knew the problem, I could try fixing it, but i don't understand the problem 
Here is the code below:

```
def get_odd_palindrome_at(s1, number):
    '''(str, int) -> str
    precondition: int is valid index in s1
        return str of longest odd palindrome, of which the middle is number. 
    '''

    if s1[number-1] != s1[number+1]:
        return s1[int]
    num =  1 
    while num < len(s1):
        if s1[number-num] == s1[number+num]: 
            num= num +1 
    return s1[number-num: number+num+1] 

get_odd_palindrome_at("AGTGAT", 2)
```

Comment: Right here > s1[number-num: number+num+1]  Check what num is at this point. And what number plus num +1 is because I bet it's bigger than the len(s1).

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.

In the statement `return s1[int]` int is not a valid index of s1

In the loop, num is going as high as len(s1)-1. At this point in the statement

> if s1[number-num] == s1[number+num]:

`number+num` is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust 2 commands to correctly check index to be in bounds, and to fix 1 error:

Instead of

```
    if s1[number-1] != s1[number+1]:         # number + 1 may be too large
        return s1[int]                       # it is error
```

use

```
    if number + 1 >= len(s1)  or  s1[number-1] != s1[number+1]:
        return s1[number]
```

and instead of

```
    while num < len(s1):                     # it isn't sufficient condition
        if s1[number-num] == s1[number+num]: # it is OK; only for context
```

use more complex but the correct condition

```
    while number - num >= 0  and  number + num <= len(s1) - 1:
        if s1[number-num] == s1[number+num]:
```

So your full code will be (I added some blank rows)

```
def get_odd_palindrome_at(s1, number):
    '''(str, int) -> str
    precondition: int is valid index in s1
        return str of longest odd palindrome, of which the middle is number. 
    '''

    if number + 1 > len(s1) - 1  or  s1[number-1] != s1[number+1]:
        return s1[number]

    num =  1

    while number - num >= 0  and  number + num <= len(s1) - 1:
        if s1[number-num] == s1[number+num]: 
            num= num +1
            print(number, num)
    return s1[number-num: number+num+1] 

get_odd_palindrome_at("AGTGAT", 2)
```